# Is it possible to share a XAML element across a whole application, as a resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xaml-resources

I would like to create a custom 'command column' for the DevExpress GridControl that has edit and delete icons, for explicit editing and deleting of grid rows. I'd like to define the template for this column once only, and refer to it as a resource in all grids I create. I don't think the weight of a UserControl is warranted in this scenario.

Comment: You can create a custom control with a `ControlTemplate` that defines you column and set it in an implicit style defined in app.xaml. this way it will apply across the entire application ...

Comment: Can't I just put the `ControlTemplate` in the resource dictionary? Why is a custom control needed?

Comment: `ControlTemplate` templates a certain control. If you make it implcitly template `DevExpress` column class it will override their default behavior which I guess you don't want, So you should create a class of your own derived from DevExpress base column class that has your logic and implicity template it.

Comment: It's the data template I want to customise, and share, not the control template.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create it as custom control. Refer the below links to create custom controls

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17830/Creating-and-consuming-a-custom-WPF-control

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49802/Create-a-WPF-Custom-Control-Part-2

http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html